# Duplicating a git repository and its GIT-LFS settings

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows, git-lfs

I've duplicated a repo into a newer repo but when doing a git clone on the new repo it's unable to download the files using the LFS pointers and I get an error when smudge is used...
e.g... "Error downloading object. Object not found on server"

Steps:

```
git clone --bare https://github.com/myuser/old-repo.git
cd old-repository.git
git push --mirror https://github.com/myuser/new-repo.git

git clone https://github.com/myuser/new-repo.git
[error.....git-lfs.exe smudge --- somefile.....Error downloading object]
```

The branches and commit histories look fine but LFS fails to download the required files. Is there another method when using git-lfs?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm trying to do the same thing, and it currently looks like I have to choose between keeping the project's history or continue using LFS. I'd rather not have to make that choice.

Answer (score 36):

I found out this link: [mirroring-a-repository-that-contains-git-large-file-storage-objects](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.7/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/duplicating-a-repository#mirroring-a-repository-that-contains-git-large-file-storage-objects)

It seems to exactly answer your question.
The important part you missed is the `git lfs push/pull`:

```
git clone --bare https://hostname/exampleuser/old-repository.git
cd old-repository.git
git lfs fetch --all
git push --mirror https://hostname/exampleuser/new-repository.git
git lfs push --all https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git
```

Comment: Well, this makes me feel like an idiot in how simple it is, but definitely accomplishes what I wanted to do. Thanks!

Comment: what does ```git push --mirror https://hostname/exampleuser/new-repository.git``` has to do with mirroring to github repository?

Answer (score 2):

Hooks and addons and such are repo-local config, if your git-lfs setup is somehow tricky to do a second time commit a repo-setup script to do it and run that on first checkout.

Answer (score 1):

You can also clone using the git protocol, LFS assets will still be pulled down via http, which may incur a password prompts depending on your LFS server, since preshared sshs key will not be used for authentication on LFS assets.

```
 git clone git@github.com:username/my_lfs_repo.git destination_dir
```