# How to migrate repositories from GitLab to GitHub

Tags: github, gitlab

One of my team members has migrated the repositories from GitLab to GitHub but it's not migrated properly later my PM assigned me to do that task. It contains some large files. I am not able to push the repo to GitHub. The size of the repo is huge as it's the full codebase for an operating system and the size of the repo is around 3.5GB files. The other repository contains below 1GB how can I migrate the entire repository from GitLab to GitHub?

Comment: Do you use git lfs in gitlab? lfs needs a special treatment as the files are not stored in the repository itself.

Comment: GitHub has an Import Code feature, if your GetLab repository is accessible remotely, it can perform all the required steps on your behalf. https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github/importing-a-repository-with-github-importer

Comment: To do a clone incl LFS files manually, refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41789052/736079

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://github.com/piceaTech/node-gitlab-2-github

You could use this github file and follow the directions. Worked for me in the past, so it should work properly for you.